# Pictures aligned side by side with single caption?

Tags: floats

I have two figures in my document but have single caption for both of them. I searched the forum and found out how to get two pics side by side but i am unable to get the single caption. Please help

[image]

this is the what i found out at the forum and used for my document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option for production version of file

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true]{fase4.pdf}
\caption{Figura experimental}
\label{fase1}
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{\fill} % it's important not to leave blank lines before and after this command
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true]{fase5.pdf}
\caption{Altra figura experimental}
\label{fase2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using subfig package :

```
%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402358/pictures-aligned-side-by-side-with-single-caption#402358

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option for production version of file

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering

  \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true]{fase4.pdf}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true]{fase5.pdf}}

\caption{Altra figura experimental}
\label{fase2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option for production version of file

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Single caption for both images}
\label{fase2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```